# vim + fzf.vim - specify project root in :Files

Tags: vim, fzf

My question is about usage of [vim-projectroot](https://github.com/dbakker/vim-projectroot) with [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim)

I have a key mapping which opens `:Files` at project root like this

`nnoremap <leader>t :ProjectRootExe Files<CR>`

But problem is it's interfering with `set autochdir`. Unless I force a new session with `:e/:sp/:vsp` current directory remains same as **previous** directory.

So I thought of passing directory as the second argument to `:Files path` like this

```
function Guess()
  return projectroot#guess()
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>t :Files Guess()<CR>
```

But for obvious reasons which I can't figure out I am unable to get the usage working. How can I specify in a vim mapping that it should combine the command with output of a function?

What I want is `:Files output_of_Guess()` to be invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim's evaluation rules are different than most programming languages. You need to use `:execute` in order to evaluate a variable (or expression); otherwise, it's taken literally; i.e. Vim uses the function name itself as the argument.

```
nnoremap <leader>t :execute 'Files ' . Guess()<CR>
```

An alternative for mappings is using `:help :map-expr`; that's basically `:execute` built into the variant of `:map`:

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>t ':Files ' . Guess() . "\<lt>CR>"
```

Comment: This is what I ended up using `nnoremap <leader>t :execute 'Files' ProjectRootGuess()<CR>`

For grepping I used this which I got from one of the issues in fzf.vim

 ```command! -nargs=* Rag
  \ call fzf#vim#ag(<q-args>, extend(s:with_git_root(), { 'down': '~40%' }))
```